# Python flask, when editing images in forms, form.image.data is empty

Tags: python, image, flask, flask-wtforms, editing

I have a form to edit an object created by another form, the editing form is not able to update the image to the new image and will display the old images.

when printing form.image.data, it is empty even though I am uploading an image file.

**init**.py

```
def edit_item(itemid):
context = {"message": ""}
item = itemcontroller.get_item_by_UID(itemid)
if(not item):
    abort(404)
form = edit_sales_item(formdata=request.form, obj=item)

if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
    f = form.image.data
    print(f)
    print(os.path.exists(PACKAGEDIR + form.UID.data))
    if(f):
        os.remove(ITEMSDIR + form.UID.data)
        f.save(ITEMSDIR + form.UID.data)
    update_form = form.data.copy()
    update_form["image_url"] = ITEMSDIR + form.UID.data

    item2 = itemcontroller.create_and_save_item(update_form)
    if (item2):
        context ={"message":"You have created a new item"}
        itemcontroller.remove_sales_item(item)
        flash("You have updated the item "+ item.get_UID() +" information")
        return redirect(url_for("admin_pages.list_sales_items"))
    else:
        context ={"error":"A error have occured..."}
return render_template('admin/editing/edit_items.html', form=form, message=context, item=item)
```

forms.py

```
class edit_sales_item(FlaskForm):
UID = StringField("Unique ID:", validators=[validators.Length(min=3, max=10),DataRequired()])
name = StringField("Name: ", validators=[validators.Length(min=3, max=200) ,DataRequired()])
description = TextAreaField("Description: ", validators=[validators.Length(min=5, max=3000) ,DataRequired()])
price = DecimalField("Price: ", validators=[DataRequired()])# Regexp(
image = FileField("Image of product: ", validators=[FileAllowed(images ,'Image only!')])
stocks = IntegerField("Stocks amount: ",  validators=[validators.NumberRange(min=1),DataRequired()])
submit = SubmitField()
```

the templates will just shows the form.

Comment: huh, why don't you put the workload of editing the picture on the frondend, with javascript?

Comment: how would i go about saving the picture into the directory i want without it being an absolute path kind of thing?